# Flutter: Image rotation on canvas and specifying pivot point

Tags: image, canvas, flutter, rotation, pivot

I am a beginner to flutter. This code rotates the images on canvas, but the pivot point is on the center. How to specify a pivot point for the rotation? Thanks.

```
Size imageSize = new Size(image.width.toDouble(), image.height.toDouble());
Size targetSize = imageSize * scale;

final double thewidth = image.width.toDouble();

final double theheight = image.height.toDouble();
final double r = (sqrt(thewidth * thewidth + theheight * theheight) / 2) * scale;

final alpha = atan(theheight / thewidth);
final beta = alpha + angle;
final shiftX = (r * cos(beta));
final shiftY = (r * sin(beta));

canvas.save();

canvas.translate(offset.dx - shiftX, offset.dy - shiftY);

canvas.rotate(angle);

paintImage(canvas: canvas, rect: Offset(0, 0) & targetSize, image: image, fit: BoxFit.fill, filterQuality: FilterQuality.high);

canvas.restore();
```

Comment: thank you, but I dont know how to use it, the flutter canvas.transform requires Float64List

Comment: can you give example how to initialize? parameters are required.

Comment: can i get the current position of the matrix after I rotated the image?

Comment: here i made a video https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FzUTJh-T1xr4j0lK7h7_oJR_LgT0PvXr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i want to rotate the image at the starting point of the selector

Comment: i guess i have to normalize the rotation first, do you have calculations?

Comment: do you see my video? why is that the image suddenly move from certain points?

Comment: `canvas.save();`

`MatrixBuilder asdf = MatrixBuilder(rotation: angle,rotationOrigin: saveselectorstarting);`

`canvas.translate(offset.dx, offset.dy);`

`canvas.transform(asdf.matrix.storage);`

`paintImage(canvas: canvas, rect: Offset(0, 0) & targetSize, image: image, fit: BoxFit.fill);`
`canvas.restore();`

Comment: as you see on my video, that canvas.translate is use so i can drag the image

Comment: there is an error `/home/glenn/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-compat-28.0.0.aar/e77286e1e10d9066e0a858ad15c4d00a/res/values/values.xml:133:5-70: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.`

Comment: yes, i guess i have to separately 2 canvas, one is to draw the rotated image and the one is to draw the selector

Comment: still not able to solve my problem.

Comment: here is a new video, i want the calculations to normalize the x and y so even the canvas is rotated i can still get the right x and y position.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GMFqVj2LsfZdY9yTyaqGdiQIjGyPDfj6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: or the blue square will always be relative to the screen touch even if the canvas is rotated. normalize the x and y given the angle.